# Count Up effect ; 2 plugins interfering

Tags: javascript

Trying to develop my website and got a problem with a jQuery plugin.

After searching through google 'till the page 9 of the the search, I've found an working JavaScript plugin that simply counts up ( I'll let a link as an exemple, it's as you scroll down a site and it displays a count up effect from 0 to a desired number in a desired amount of time).

It works amazing - and not gonna lie, it's the the only functional one I found in 8 pages of internet- but, if i try to copy+paste the plugin on the site( like, to double it) it blows the first plugin and they interfere with each other ( no matter what number i set the second one to count till, it will count as the first one). Basically, they blow each other up.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/YWn9t/

My question:

Why is this thing happening? My hand-errors or?

As far as my experience with coding takes me, i know each plugin has some kind of name, like to indentify which is which. May this be the base of the error? Like, i have to change the name of the second? And if yes, which line/ lines should i modify?

Do you have this kind of plugin?

L.E.: Forgot to mention. I use a sitebuilder: WebWave so it must have a css code, html and jv code.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});

    // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
    var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
      increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;

    return $(this).each(function() {
      var _this = this,
        loopCount = 0,
        value = options.from,
        interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

      function updateTimer() {
        value += increment;
        loopCount++;
        $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));

        if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
          options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
        }

        if (loopCount >= loops) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          value = options.to;

          if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
            options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };

  $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0, // the number the element should start at
    to: 100, // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000, // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100, // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 0, // the number of decimal places to show
    onUpdate: null, // callback method for every time the element is updated,
    onComplete: null, // callback method for when the element finishes updating
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
  $('.timer').countTo({
    from: 50,
    to: 2500,
    speed: 5000,
    refreshInterval: 50,
    onComplete: function(value) {
      console.debug(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.timer {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px
}

#help {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="timer"></span>
<hr/>
<span id="help">From: 50 - To: 2500 / Over 5000 Milli-Seconds</span>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. PS: JAVA is NOT JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Works for me when I use unique IDs

Remove the display:block to align horizontally

For example

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.countTo = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});
    var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
      increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;
    return $(this).each(function() {
      var _this = this,
        loopCount = 0,
        value = options.from,
        interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

      function updateTimer() {
        value += increment;
        loopCount++;
        $(_this).html(value.toFixed(options.decimals));
        if (typeof(options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
          options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
        }
        if (loopCount >= loops) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          value = options.to;
          if (typeof(options.onComplete) == 'function') {
            options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  };
  $.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0,
    to: 100,
    speed: 1000,
    refreshInterval: 100,
    decimals: 0,
    onUpdate: null,
    onComplete: null,
  };
})(jQuery);

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#timer1').countTo({
    from: 50,
    to: 2500,
    speed: 5000,
    refreshInterval: 50,
    onComplete: function(value) {
      console.debug(this);
    }
  });
  $('#timer2').countTo({
    from: 1550,
    to: 4500,
    speed: 5000,
    refreshInterval: 50,
    onComplete: function(value) {
      console.debug(this);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.timer {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 50px;
}

#help {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px
}

#container {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <span class="timer" id="timer1"></span>
  <span class="timer" id="timer2"></span>
</div>
<hr/>
<span id="help">From: 50 - To: 2500 / Over 5000 Milli-Seconds</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer ^
Yet; i'd have 2 questions
1. Is it mandatory to have an unique code for both numbers(2500, 4500 in thsi case)?
2. How can i allign them horrizontaly?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by mandatory unique code. You need to identify two different spans so you cannot use a class they both have. And because they are spans, you just remove dispay:block to align thn horizontally

Comment: I thank you one more time for trying to help. It's appreciated.
Yet. Not sure why, your code delets all the images from my sites, and they comeback once i delete it. Also, even if it works when i press "Run" here on site, the numbers ain't appearing either on the site.
Also, about horizontally alignment; tried to delete "display:block" and it didn't work. Moreover, tried with "float: left", "display: block-inline". Not one of them made it horizontally :( . 

And the last thing over, there is a weird 1-2px white line which i can't find it in the CSS code to remove :-?

Comment: I have no idea. Sounds like a paste error. You can send me a url via my site in my profile you want me to take a look